# Is it possible to simulate Nasa's R2 robot on ROS Noetic?

Tags: simulation, ros, robotics, gazebo-simu, rospy

Steps I followed:

Step 1: Installed controllers and other things using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-ros-control ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-control ros-noetic-joint-state-controller ros-noetic-effort-controllers ros-noetic-joint-trajectory-controller ros-noetic-moveit* ros-noetic-octomap* ros-noetic-object-recognition-*
```

Step 2:I tried cloning this repository but it is missing:

```
git clone -b noetic-devel https://bitbucket.org/nasa_ros_pkg/nasa_r2_simulator.git
```